# In MS Word use macro to replace hyperlink text containing "#" and "!"

Tags: vba, url, ms-word, wildcard

In a Microsoft Word document, using a macro I want to change links like
`https://www.library/#!/xyz` to `https://www.library2/xyz` (where xyz indicates the specific resource and all other parts of these strings are constant).

The problem is that the "#!" characters in the original URL seem to terminate the string found by `link.Address` (and the "#!" is part of the original copied link -- not something I have a choice about).

My code:

```vb
Sub statelinks() 
    For Each link In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks 
        MsgBox link.Address 
    Next
End Sub
```

For a document with one hyperlink `https://www-clinicalkey-com.proxy.library.emory.edu/#!/content/book/3-s2.0-B9780323393041000038?scrollTo=%23hl0001812`
the `MsgBox` shows `https://www-clinicalkey-com.proxy.library.emory.edu/` (truncated immediately before the "#!").

How can I get the full URL?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use `link.TextToDisplay` - **if it is identical** to the address itself.

Or you can "hack" it a little bit joining address and subaddress - as Word vba assumes the # to be the divider for the subaddress

`link.Address & "#" & link.SubAddress`

This doesn't work if there are two `#`s in the URL ...

Comment: Ike -- Wonderful. Thank you!  I didn't know that the "#" divided the URL into address and subaddress. Knowing from your answer that this is the case and that I could learn the subaddress with link.subaddress beautifully solved my problem. Very appreciative. Doug